# Number of lattice points contained in the unit ball is asymptotic to $L^2$ times the measure of the unit ball.

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, geometric-topology

Suppose I want to count the number of points of $\mathbb{Z}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which have length at most $L$.

This is equivalent to counting the number of points of $\frac{1}{L} \mathbb{Z}^2$ contained in the unit ball.

I am reading a set of notes that states that the number of points of $\frac{1}{L} \mathbb{Z}^2$ contained in the unit ball is asymptotic to $L^2$ times the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball.

The notes state that the Lebesgue measure (of what?) can be defined as the limit as $L \to \infty$ of
$$\frac{1}{L^2} \sum_{\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \delta_{1/L \alpha}$$
where $\delta_x$ denotes the point mass at $x$.

(1). What is the above limit the Lebesgue measure of?

(2). Why is the number of points of $\frac{1}{L} \mathbb{Z}^2$ contained in the unit ball asymptotic to $L^2$ times the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball?

PS: I don't know what field of mathematics this type of question belongs to, any reference recommendation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).  Intuitively, you are shrinking the integer lattice by a factor $L$ in all directions.  Each cell represents an area of $\frac 1{L^2}$.  The limit counts these cells.  The number of cells increases as $L^2$.  The number of questionable cells (those near the perimeter so they might be in or out) only increases as $L$, so the error decreases as $\frac 1L$

Comment: As far as I understand, the Lebesgue measure counts the number of cells of dimension $1/L^2$, but to what "space" we are assigning this Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Is it obvious that the number of cells increases as $L^2$? If so, why does this imply that the number of lattice points of length less than $1/L$ contained in the unit circle grows at a rate of $L^2$?

Comment: The area of each cell is $\frac 1{L^2}$, while the area of the circle is fixed.  You have to have at least as many cells that are partly or wholly inside the circle as $\frac {\piL^2}4$